# InApp weird behaviour: "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded."

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I'm testing some in-app purchases in my app, and encountered strange behaviour (bug?). When internet connection died after making in-app, and transaction failed, it keeps prompting me for App Store credentials at the app start, and when i try to purchase - it gives "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded."

There was some similar questions here, but none of them covered what is happening, 'cause:

- Purchase is not a consumable.
- No content is hosted on apple servers.
- It was finished via finish transaction
- At the app start, when it asks for credentials (as soon as i make my app transaction observer), pending queue is empty (0 transactions)
- It doesn't call 'update transaction' thing at that time
- Reseting device, logging out from iTunes, deleting provisioning profiles do not help, it still prompts for credentials, payment queue still empty.

How does it even know, that content from my server was not downloaded yet? I even tried to finish the transaction before even starting download (bad design, i know, but what a heck), it was removed (lol, callback triggered, queue empty). Then i disconnected internet/ killed app, and somehow magically it prompted me for credentials when i started it again...

Comment: `InApp` are managed from Apple Server, so deleting or, updating profile, or, reinstalling app won't affect the `InApp` in any case, the behavior is absolutely correct, it says that `your transaction was done`, but somehow the download was failed, sometime in inapp you need to handle transaction error codes too.. To make it work freshly use a different apple id.

Comment: Ok, that part i do understand. But error code is 2, could not connect to app store... I could make a workaround and trigger downloading for failed transactions with error code 2, i send receipt after all to validate purchase. But it downloading that content does not help to finish that transaction, every time i open app i get that prompt for credentials... That would be extremely annoying for user, and what more, i don's see how i could do anything about it

Comment: Error codes are same in the situation described above, and when user cancel purchase (both have error.code = 2). It seems indistinguishable.